# Unable to get attribute value in jquery using val function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a textfield to pass the value. That value is passing on a HTML button. I want that button value inside a jQuery variable. The problem is that I just want that button value which is passed by jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myvaluefirst').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#display_here').html($(this).val());
  })
});

function getval() {
  alert($('#display_here').val());
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here" onclick="getval();">value will display here</button>
```

Comment: Change `alert($('#display_here').val());` to `alert($('#display_here').text());`

Comment: if you input on `input field: "some text"` then, what will be `button value` and what you want your jquery variable value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery `val()` is used for `value` attributes, in your code you are using `button` element, you should call `text()` method, buttons don't have `value` attributes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myvaluefirst').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#display_here').html($(this).val());
  })
});

function getval() {
  // alert($('#display_here').val()); // Edit this as below
  alert($('#display_here').text());
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here" onclick="getval();">value will display here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text or html property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myvaluefirst').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#display_here').html($(this).val());
  })
});

function getval() {
  alert($('#display_here').text());
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here" onclick="getval();">value will display here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use inline event handlers. As you've already included jQuery in the page, use it to bind an unobtrusive event handler to the button.

Secondly, the issue is because you're looking at the `value` of the button, yet you set its content. Use `text()` instead of `val()`.

Also note that I changed the `change` event to `input` so that the value of the button updates immediately. When using `change` the value doesn't update until the textbox loses focus, which can cause the button to move and the user may miss the click. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $button = $('#display_here').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  $('#myvaluefirst').on('input', function(e) {
    $button.text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here">value will display here</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myvaluefirst').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#display_here').html($(this).val());
    $('#display_here').val($(this).val());
  })
});

function getval() {
  alert($('#display_here').val()); 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myvaluefirst" id="myvaluefirst">
<button type="button" id="display_here" name="display_here" onclick="getval();">value will display here</button>
```